# Finding anchor inside span element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code in my html

```
<span id="u_0_10">You can also <a rel="my_Feed" href="#" ajaxify="send_notify?Qid=10&amp;part=99">feed</a>Send me this feed</span>
```

I want to know can I find that anchor with jQuery and fire its onclick in jQuery?

Comment: Have you read the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/)? Done any research at all? This is something to answer after about a minute in Google, or Bing...

Comment: none of the answer accepted. still searching for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/sVtbh/3/)**

```
$('#u_0_10 a').click(function(){
   alert($(this).text()); 
});

$('#u_0_10 a').click();
```

You can learn more about jQuery [**selectors**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [**click**](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event here.

Answer (score 0):

This css should work.

"span#u_0_10 a"

Answer (score 0):

$('#u_0_10 > a').each(function() {
    // do your stuff
});

Answer (score 0):

Since noone clicked the link I'll do it

`$('#u_0_10 > a').trigger("click")`

Answer (score 0):

try this code

**For particular span with id myId**

```
  $('#myId a').click(function() {
   / process click event here
 });
```

**For all the span with css myKlass**

```
 $('.myKlass a').click(function() {
   / process click event here
 });
```

**For All the span**

```
 $('span a').click(function() {
   / process click event here
 });
```